# Different output format than expected

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, newline

I have written code to read following text file

```
Generated by trjconv : a bunch of waters t=   0.00000
 3000
    1SOL     OW    1  -1.5040   2.7580   0.6820
    1SOL    HW1    2   1.4788   2.7853   0.7702
    1SOL    HW2    3   1.4640   2.8230   0.6243
    2SOL     OW    4   1.5210   0.9510   2.2050
    2SOL    HW1    5  -1.5960   0.9780   2.1520
    2SOL    HW2    6   1.4460   0.9940   2.1640
 1000SOL     OW 2998   1.5310   1.7952   2.1981
 1000SOL    HW1 2999   1.4560   1.7375  -2.1836
 1000SOL    HW2 3000   1.6006   1.7369   2.2286
 3.12736   3.12736   3.12736
Generated by trjconv : a bunch of waters t= 9000.00000
 3000
    1SOL     OW    1   1.1579   0.4255   2.1329
    1SOL    HW1    2   1.0743   0.3793   2.1385
```

Written Code:

```
F = open('Data.gro', 'r')
A = open('TTT.txt', 'w')
XO = []
I = range(1, 10)
with open('Data.gro') as F:
    for line in F:
        if line.split()[0] == '3000':
            A.write('Frame' + '\n')
            for R in I:
                line = next(F)
                P = line.split()
                x = float(P[3])
                XO.append(x)
                if line.split()[2] == '3000':
                   print('Oxygen atoms XYZ coordinates:')
                   A.write('Oxygen atoms XYZ coordinates:' + '\n')
                   A.write("%s\n" % (XO))
                   XO
                   XO[0] - XO[1]
                   XO = []
               else:
                   pass
        else:
            pass


A.close()
```

First problem:

My problem is Out put text file looks like as follows in one line. It printed as a one line in text file.

```
FrameOxygen atoms XYZ coordinates:[-1.504, 1.4788, 1.464, 1.521, -1.596, 1.446, 1.531, 1.456, 1.6006]FrameOxygen atoms XYZ coordinates:[1.1579, 1.0743, 1.1514, 2.2976, 2.2161, 2.3118, 2.5927, -2.5927, 2.5365]
```

Output Should be like below.

```
Frame
Oxygen atoms XYZ coordinates:
[-1.504, 1.4788, 1.464, 1.521, -1.596, 1.446, 1.531, 1.456, 1.6006]
Frame
Oxygen atoms XYZ coordinates:
[1.1579, 1.0743, 1.1514, 2.2976, 2.2161, 2.3118, 2.5927, -2.5927, 2.5365]
```

But when I am reading it shows the '\n' at the end of each separated point. 
Does any one have a idea.

Second Problem

Next problem is this only generate when I copy paste codes into a python shell. If double click my 'code.py' file it is not generating out put file. There is no error when I copy paste codes into python shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anthoney is Correct.

Windows has this issue. use WordPad to open the file.

Answer (score 4):

1) Which platform and editor you are using?

'\n' should work as expected.

I suspect you are running the code in Windows and you used notepad to inspect the file. Try use Wordpad or other more capable editor to open TTT.txt. The result should be as expected.

2) If you're doubling clicking the script in MS Windows, you are very likely to have missed some exceptions printed by python. Try run it in a command prompt:

```
python code.py
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question:

`'\n'`, an escaped `n`, is the newline character.

To answer your second question:

A frequent problem when pasting into a shell is that the pasting occurs faster than the shell processes it, meaning that the lines could be ignored by the shell.

Another issue you might have, particularly if you're pasting the above code into a shell, is the inconsistent indentation.

Your if and else are not lined up, probably because you only indented 3 spaces from the preceding line.

```
                if line.split()[2] == '3000':
                   print('Oxygen atoms XYZ coordinates:')
                   A.write('Oxygen atoms XYZ coordinates:' + '\n')
                   A.write("%s\n" % (XO))
                   XO
                   XO[0] - XO[1]
                   XO = []
               else:
                   pass
```

Also, you could nest your openings of files. In particular, this line is redundant, and could be removed:

```
F = open('Data.gro', 'r')
```

And you can do this:

```
...
with open('Data.gro') as F:
    with open('TTT.txt', 'w') as A:
    ...
```

So that if you have an error writing your file, you will still at least close it. (which means you can remove the A.close() at the end.)

Comment: I am not clear what your going to say. I used     '\n'

Comment: In the shell its working properly and generate output file. But when i double click my code file '.py' file its not generating output file read question carefully.